# Any solution to share private persistent data among apps?

Tags: android, iphone, ios, authentication, mobile

The targeted platforms are iOS and Android.

What I'm trying is to write down a token somewhere for authentication purpose, which can be accessed by my own apps (more than one), but strictly inaccessible to other apps. Why need this solution is once user registered in the first app, no need for him to do registration/login again in other apps under my company. On a web browser environment the equivalent thing could be cookie protected by domain, which can be use to store user identity for different sub-domain.

Any official way to achieve this? or any hack (no jailbreak needed)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [parse ios_guide](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide) for persistent data.

Then I think its not possible to share data between apps without adding 3rd party dependency,

U can use **webservice** for your requirement.

Comment: Thanks Prince, but if we don't think about adding 3rd party dependency, any idea about it? how it share data between apps?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about iOS but on Android, anything your app persists, no matter where it is persisted, is available on a rooted phone.  I can browse to anywhere I like using Root Explorer.  Relying on someone not finding a file is a bad design for security/authentication.

The most you could do would be to obscure it (for example, write it to one of the cache directories where users are unlikely to look) but a quick decompile will reveal that if someone really wants to bypass your security.

Same goes for encrypting it because you must store the key inside your app in some way.

I ***believe*** the same to be true for iOS if the device is jailbroken.

Thus, your requirement "strictly inaccessible to other apps" cannot be met.

Comment: Thank Simon. I admit "strictly inaccessible to other apps" is an incorrect expression. What I'm trying to save is a session ID, which is hard to guess and inaccessible to other apps, but better not to rely on using webview or browser.

Comment: OK.  There are many discussions on here related to this and the consensus amongst the elders is that the best you can do is to obsfucate.  Because you don't want a rooted solution, your only option is to store the file in external storage (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).  You could hash or encrypt the value which would prevent 99% of your users from accessing it and then obscure the underlying value using an algorithm in your code which morphs the value in and out of your app, thereby preventing 99% of the 1% gaining access.